# Missing property prefix in the order by clause of a Cypher query

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I have a Spring Data Neo4j repository with a pageable list.

The repository looks like:

```
public interface Neo4JPartRepository extends GraphRepository<Neo4JPart> {

  @Query("MATCH (p:Neo4JPart) RETURN p")
  public Page<Neo4JPart> all(Pageable page);

}
```

But when I run it, the generated Cypher query is missing the p. prefix before the serialNumber property:

```
message=serialNumber not defined (line 1, column 39 (offset: 38))
"MATCH (p:Neo4JPart) RETURN p ORDER BY serialNumber ASC SKIP 0 LIMIT 11"
```

The Cypher query works fine on the browser client if I type it like:

```
MATCH (p:Neo4JPart) RETURN p ORDER BY p.serialNumber ASC SKIP 0 LIMIT 11
```

Am I doing something wrong using Neo4j ?

I must say I'm doing here my first Neo4j application and am comming from a JPA world where I was doing something somewhat similar that works fine.

The JPA repository is:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u")
public Page<User> all(Pageable page);
```

The service is:

```
@Override
public Page<User> all(Pageable page) {
  logger.debug("============>> Sort: " + page.getSort());
    return userRepository.all(page);
}
```

with the console log showing:

```
============>> Sort: firstname: ASC
```

and below:

```
select
    user0_.id as id1_18_,
    user0_.version as version2_18_,
    user0_.confirmed_email as confirme3_18_,
    user0_.email as email4_18_,
    user0_.firstname as firstnam5_18_,
    user0_.lastname as lastname6_18_,
    user0_.password as password7_18_,
    user0_.password_salt as password8_18_,
    user0_.readable_password as readable9_18_,
    user0_.work_phone as work_ph10_18_ 
from
    user_account user0_ 
order by
    user0_.firstname asc limit ?
```

UPATE: 
If I do not pass any Sort order to the Cypher query and have the repository like:

```
  @Query("MATCH (p:Neo4JPart) RETURN p ORDER BY p.serialNumber")
  public Page<Neo4JPart> all(Pageable page);
```

then it works fine and orders the returned list of elements.

It's a work around, but, from a JPA legacy standpoint, it does not yet work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use fully qualified names in your sort, i.e. `p.firstname`

SDN cannot know which identifiers you use in your cypher statement.